# Android Volley onResponse get data

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonresponse

In a string post request for logging in. in onResponse all i am returned is the status code of 200. I would like to get the data returned as well. I am not sure where to go from this point forward? Any ideas on how to get the data returned, and not just the status code?

```
    public void requestWithSomeHttpHeaders() {

    try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "http://......";
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("username", "yourusername");
        jsonBody.put("password", "yourpassword");
        final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                    System.out.println(responseString);
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Was it really necessary to implement more than the `onResponse` and `onError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably, define a method.

```
private void doLogin() {
    // TODO: startActivity?
}
```

Then call that

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("VOLLEY", response);

            doLogin();
        }
```

If you want the data from the server, that is what `String response` is. Check your Logcat.

As mentioned in the comments, using `StringRequest` without implementing `getBody`, `parseNetworkResponse`, and `getBodyContentType` might work better.

Comment: In logcat all i see is I/VOLLEY: 200

Comment: If i do something similar in Google Postman i get returned all kinds of data.

Comment: I don't know what your URL is, but it seems to be just returning `"200"`. If that is an issue, it's all server-side, not a Volley problem

Comment: Try using `StringRequest` without implementing `getBody` or `parseNetworkResponse` or `getBodyContentType`

Comment: That worked, Thanks! My API currently requires the username, and password sent in the body. I removed parseNetworkResponse, and reworked getBody to
return mRequestBody.toString().getBytes();

Comment: If you are getting JSON returned, then you might want JSONObjectRequest instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse JSON add method like this

```
 public Profile getUserProfile(String response){
    Profile profile = null;
    try {
        profile = new Profile();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            profile.setId(jsonObject.getInt(context.getString(R.string.profile_id)));
        profile.setLastName(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.profile_lastName)));
        profile.setName(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.profile_name)));
        profile.setEmail(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.profile_email)));


    } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return profile;
}
```

In your onResponse method

```
     @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //If you have son object
           Profile profile = getUserProfile(response)
        }
```